# customTypeMapping['JSON'] - Not Working properly in Apollo Graphql Android

Tags: json, kotlin, graphql

My build.gradle file is

```
customTypeMapping['JSON'] = "kotlin.Any"
```

My graphql file is

```
mutation UpdatePropertyInfo(
    $id: ID
    $extra_beds: [JSON])
{
    update_property_info(
        id: $id
        extra_beds: $extra_beds
}
```

Auto generated file graphql model file

```
data class UpdatePropertyInfoMutation(
  val id: Input<String> = Input.absent(),
  val extra_beds: Input<List<Any?>> = Input.absent(),
) : Mutation<UpdatePropertyInfoMutation.Data, UpdatePropertyInfoMutation.Data, Operation.Variables>
    {}
```

When I pass a JSON list the format is like this

```
[["BedsModel(beds_count=0, bedroom_bedtype=[Bedroom_bedtype(_id=5ec23a7221866f101a184868, name=Sofa bed, status=active, updated_at=0, created_at=0, __v=0, id=5ec23a7221866f101a184868, count=0), Bedroom_bedtype(_id=5ec23a7e21866f101a184869, name=Couch, status=active, updated_at=0, created_at=0, __v=0, id=5ec23a7e21866f101a184869, count=0), Bedroom_bedtype(_id=5ec23a8921866f101a18486a, name=Floor mattress, status=active, updated_at=0, created_at=0, __v=0, id=5ec23a8921866f101a18486a, count=0)])"]
```

But i need format like this

```
 [[{"bedroom_bedtype":[{"__v":0,"_id":"5ec23a7221866f101a184868","count":0,"created_at":0,"id":"5ec23a7221866f101a184868","name":"Sofa bed","status":"active","updated_at":0},{"__v":0,"_id":"5ec23a7e21866f101a184869","count":0,"created_at":0,"id":"5ec23a7e21866f101a184869","name":"Couch","status":"active","updated_at":0},{"__v":0,"_id":"5ec23a8921866f101a18486a","count":0,"created_at":0,"id":"5ec23a8921866f101a18486a","name":"Floor mattress","status":"active","updated_at":0}],"beds_count":0}]]
```

please help me to get this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed like this way,Its working now.

```
override fun encode(value: Any): CustomTypeValue<*> {
           when (value) {
               is MutableList<*> -> {
                   val str: String = Gson().toJson(value)
                   val type: Type = object : TypeToken<List<Map1<String, Any>>>() {}.type
                   val myMap: List<Map1<String, Any>> = Gson().fromJson(str, type)
                   return CustomTypeValue.GraphQLJsonList(myMap)
               }
               else -> {  
                   return CustomTypeValue.fromRawValue(value)
               }
           }
       }
```